Vico Charts in Jeptack Compose
type here.                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                        while (isActive) {
                            modelProducer.tryRunTransaction {

                                columnSeries {
                                    repeat(Defaults.MULTI_SERIES_COUNT) {
                                        series(
                                            List(Defaults.ENTRY_COUNT) {
                                                Defaults.COLUMN_LAYER_MIN_Y +
                                                        Random.nextFloat() * Defaults.COLUMN_LAYER_RELATIVE_MAX_Y
                                            }
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            delay(Defaults.TRANSACTION_INTERVAL_MS)
                        }
                    }
                }

                CartesianChartHost(
                    chart =
                    rememberCartesianChart(
                        rememberColumnCartesianLayer(
                            ColumnCartesianLayer.ColumnProvider.series(
                                columnColors.map {
                                    rememberLineComponent(
                                        color = it,
                                        thickness = 8.dp,
                                        shape = shape
                                    )
                                }
                            )
                        ),
                        startAxis = rememberStartAxis(
                            label = rememberAxisLabelComponent(
                                color = Color.Black,
                                textSize = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.fontSize
                            )
                        ),
                        bottomAxis = rememberBottomAxis(
                            label = rememberAxisLabelComponent(
                                color = Color.Black
                            )
                        ),
                        decorations = remember(horizontalBox) { listOf(horizontalBox) },
                    ),
                    modelProducer = modelProducer,

                    marker = rememberMarker(),
                    runInitialAnimation = false,
                    zoomState = rememberVicoZoomState(zoomEnabled = true),
                )
            }
        }
    }

if some of you know vico charts you should know that every chart has animation and I set one of the charts and now I cannot stop animation in chart I tried everything but I cannot solve it therfore I need your help who knows how to solve it I make false runinitalAnimation , it didn't work!
